# MysqliDb- Update API (foreign key bug)

Tags: php, rest

I am currently having trouble with table association in mysql database where I will input a payload in JSON format and put it in the document_type_id (this is a foreign key from tbl_documents table in product database, that connects to the id from tbl_document_types table which is also a table under product database). The problem is, it always echo's out that the payload['document_type_id'] doesn't found any match even if it has a similar value in the tbl_document_types. Here is the code that I created for this method

Here is the code that I created for this method

```
$document_type_id = $payload['document_type_id'];
$document_type = $this->db->where('id', $document_type_id)->getOne('tbl_document_types');

if (!$document_type) {
      echo json_encode(array(
           'method' => 'PUT',
           'status' => 'fail',
           'data' => [],
           'message' => 'Document type not found'
      ));
      return;
}
```

Comment: You just have a where clause only in your code. Where are the select and from clauses?